# Excel: Making SetFilterDateRange include events that began before the selected begin date as long as they carried into the chosen range

Tags: vba, excel

I have a worksheet that gets data from a Microsoft Project timeline. In my Excel worksheet, I want to filter out everything except for tasks that are happening from the current day until 7 days from the current day. Here's the code I have that does that:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click ()
    ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches ("NativeTimeline_Filter_Date").TimelineState. _
    SetFilterDateRange Date, DateAdd ("d",7, Date)
End Sub
```

The problem with that is that if I have a multi-day task that started the day before the filter's start date, it will be filtered out even though it carries into the range I want to see. Does anyone know how I can re-write this code so it includes these multi-day tasks? Thanks!

Edit, for an example. Because this is work related I can't share the data, but it's two columns, one for date and one for task. So a short snippet of the input might look like this:

```
Th 03/02              |   Task 1
Fr 03/03 to Th 03/09  |   Task 2
Fr 03/10              |   Task 3
Mo 03/13              |   Task 4
Tu 03/14 to We 03/15  |   Task 5
```

When I apply my filter to show only tasks from today until 7 days from now, I'd WANT it to show only the rows with tasks 2 through 4. What DOES happen is that I get the rows with tasks 3 through 5 because the start date of task 2 falls outside of my range.

Comment: Could you post samples of your data and desired output?

Comment: @MarkFitzgerald Hey, I edited my original post with a barebones example. It's work related, so I can't share the actual data, but I think the example explains it pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind splitting your End Date into a separate column, you can probably do this without VBA using a nested IF OR AND formula:
[image: Nested IF OR AND]

Columns D and E aren't used in the formula but I included them to show the components of the OR expression.  Column D heading should be "A > today AND < today + 7" but I changed the formula without changing the heading.

If adding columns isn't an option then it could be done in VBA but it would be a non-trivial task:

- FOR each row of data:
- Get the Start Date as a string from column A "Th 03/02"
- Convert that to a date variable *StartDate*
- Test if column A has "to" in it
- If it does then extract the End Date as a string
- Convert that date to another variable *EndDate*
- Test `If StartDate >= Today And EndDate < Today + 7 then`
- `TestRow.EntireRow.Hidden = False Else TestRow.EntireRow.Hidden = True`